# Java's Math.pow is returning off by 1 error

Tags: java

If I run `Math.pow(15, 14)` in Java, the result comes out as

```
29192926025390624
```

However, if I run 15^14 in a scientific calculator in windows, it returns

```
29192926025390625
```

Is this because `Math.pow(a, b)` uses `double` for its calculation?

If that is so, what is the best way to solve this kind of problem? (e.g. getting correct answer for 15^14 in Java)

Comment: The best answer depends on the exact mathematical properties your application needs. Note that if this behavior surprises you, your instinctive response to the question "what mathematical properties does my application need" may not be accurate.

Comment: A double is precise to about 15.9 decimal digits. Your value has 17. You can't get a quart out of a pint pot.

Comment: The answer was already given, but a general remark: If you want to compute a power that is only involving integer numbers, then you should consider creating your own `pow` method that operates on `long` values. Not only it will solve the precision issue here, it will also be much more efficient (if implemented properly, with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rounding error is as you suspect because of the floating point arithmetic used by `Math.pow()`. A `double` can't hold the value `29192926025390625`, as demonstrated by this snippet:

```
double d = 29192926025390625L;
System.out.println(d);
```

which prints

```
2.9192926025390624E16
```

You can use `BigInteger` to avoid rounding issues:

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("15");
BigInteger result = b.pow(14);
```

Comment: Actually for 15^14 a `long` is sufficient. Also, once one uses any integer instead of floats, the problem to be avoided is *overflow*, not rounding.

Comment: @delnan: The problem here is rounding, see my edits.

Comment: @delnan keppil is right, `Math.pow()` deals return values in `double` which gets rounded in `long`conversion

Comment: When you use floating point numbers, for example through `Math.pow`, it's rounding. When using integer types, there is no rounding, only overflow. That's why I said "once one uses any integer instead of floats" -- I was one step ahead, thinking of a `long`-based solution.